# How to insert one model's data into another model in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I am setting up module in odoo where need to mainain orignal data of one model (Registrations) as logs into other model (RegistrationLogs).
I want to insert Registration model's data into RegistrationLogs via wizard call and orignal model's data need to be updated.

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Yes, question is not clear..

Answer (score 0):

you can add `many2one` field on `registration.logs` model to comodel `registraion`, on `create` function of model `registration`, hit `create` function of `registration.logs` too. to update data, setting up fields on registration logs model to `computed` or `related` will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the first initialize;

```
log_register_value = fields.Float(compute="_register_value_compute")

def _log_register_value_compute(self):
  self.log_register_value = self.register_value
```

after that you can choose an api method and apply.

take look at: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference